# force Division by zero default to NaN instead of Inf

Tags: r, division, divide-by-zero

I'm wondering if there might be a setting I'm overlooking to force `R` to return `NaN` instead of ±`Inf` when dividing by zero.

I too often findmyself doing something like

```
 results[is.infinite(results)] <- NaN
```

I'm hoping to skip the filtering/search process altogether.

---

#### Example:

```
### Example:

num <- c(1:5, NA)
denom <- -2:3

quotient <- num / denom
[1] -0.5 -2.0  Inf  4.0  2.5   NA

# desired results
[1] -0.5 -2.0  NaN  4.0  2.5   NA
```

Simple way of achieving the desired results is:

```
quotient[is.infinite(quotient)] <- NaN
```

What I am wondering is if that last step can be avoided while still getting the same desired results.

Comment: This doesn't exactly help, but `is.finite` will return `FALSE` for `NA`, `NaN` and `Inf`.

Comment: not to mention why should R put Inf. dividing by zero is not Inf. it is undefined. it should be NA. I hoped your question would instigate a better discussion of this behavior.

Comment: @Elad663 is absolutely correct.  Putting 1/0 = Inf is plainly incorrect.  Voting up for drawing attention to that.

Answer (score 4):

I would switch my predicate rather than trying to redefine math:

```
 R> is.finite(c(Inf, NA, NaN))    
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE 
 R> is.infinite(c(Inf, NA, NaN))   
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE 
 R> is.na(c(Inf, NA, NaN)) 
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 R>
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk, but I dont follow how changing the predicate helps here. What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of setting `NaN` and then testing for it, just test for `!is.finite()`.  You'll be better off in the long run as x / 0 really is Inf for all positive x.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel above is wrong concerning `x/0`. ` x/0` is not infinity---not in algebra, not in calculus, not in programming.  Consider `x =1`.  The right- and left-hand limits as `y->0` of `x/y` do not agree.  The left-hand limit is `-inf` and the right-hand limit is `inf`.  Those are not the same limit.

Comment: Ooops. Thanks for the correction.  `is.finite()` and friends still do the right things though.

Answer (score 0):

Would these properties be helpful? `0*Inf` is `NaN` and `NaN+Inf` is also `NaN`, so trying something like this would also give your desired outcome:

```
quotient <- (num / denom)*0 + (num / denom)
## [1] -0.5 -2.0  NaN  4.0  2.5   NA
```